# Prove that if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} n[f(x_0+1/n)-f(x_0)]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

I've just started to study differentiation and this problem really haunts me in my sleep, because I feel like I know what the solution is going to look like I am just not able to execute it. I think I should use the definition of derivative than somehow use the Hein definition of limits. But these are just my ideas and I don't know how to use them. Could you please help me by giving me some hints or solutions. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: What exactly do you want to prove? $\lim_{n\to\infty} n[f(x_0+1/n)-f(x_0)]$ is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: Write it as $f(x_0+1/n)-f(x_0)\over 1/n$. Note $1/n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Perhaps this recalls something...

Comment: @MartinR please don't get angry with me sir, I'm just a little child in a scary world, trying to solve my problems. I'm new here so thank you so much for your advice. I will try to do my best to make my question clearer. thank you, thank you sir

Comment: @DavidMitra thanks, could you give me one more hint?-how do i change the variable.?

Comment: Well, $f'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}{ f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\over h}$.  Consider what happens when $h=1/n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra thank you, you've just saved my day. Now I understand everything.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then there exists finite the following limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}$$ hence just substitute $x= x_0 + 1/n$